# Saving or using the seeds

Tags: 1000-amps

As it can be seen on the screenshot, I have seven seeds. What are they for? Shall I keep them or use them? Do I get anything for hording the seeds?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 5 seeds to fully power up a room, without having to touch all the energy nodes. Of course, the 5 seeds will be expended.

Comment: Do you happen to know if using seeds is sometimes mandatory or if I can keep them all till the end?

Comment: @wok Sorry, don't know that for sure, I've yet to fully explore the game.